# Adding ACF to CUSTOM wp api endpoints

Tags: php, wordpress, endpoint, advanced-custom-fields, wp-api

I'm writing a custom endpoint for WP API, to retrieve posts from wordpress that for example are from the 'real_estate' post_type and capacity for '5 or more' persons.

I've built a new custom endpoint:

```
// permite que meta_key e meta_value 
// sejam filtrados pela api
function filtros( $valid_vars ) {
    $valid_vars = array_merge( 
        $valid_vars, 
            array( 
                'meta_key', 
                'meta_value' ) );
    return $valid_vars;
}
add_filter( 'rest_query_vars', 'filtros' );
// funcção que retorna posts do autor
function busca( $data ) {
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'imoveis',
        'posts_per_page'    =>  '1000',
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'  =>  'AND',
            array(
                'key'   =>  'transacao',
                'value' => $data['tipo']
            ),
            array(
                'key'   =>  'quartos',
                'value' => $data['quartos'],
                'compare'   =>  '>'
            )
        )
    ));

    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'sem resultados', 'quartos: ' . $data['quartos'] . ' transacao: '. $data['tipo'], array( 'status' => 404 ) );
    }
    return $posts;
}
// cria o endpoint que ira receber a função acima
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'busca/v2', '/resultado/(?P<tipo>.+)/(?P<quartos>\d+)', 
        array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'busca',

        ) 
    );
});
```

The search is fine, it's working, i'm filtering by transaction type (sale or rent) and number of rooms in each real estate.

But my JSON response is missing a lot of fields, including ACF.
EX:
     {
          "ID":149,
          "post_author":"2",
          "post_date":"2016-03-03 23:53:39",
          "post_date_gmt":"2016-03-03 23:53:39",
          "post_content":"",
          "post_title":"Oportunidade do Ano",
          "post_excerpt":"",
          "post_status":"publish",
          "comment_status":"closed",
          "ping_status":"closed",
          "post_password":"",
          "post_name":"oportunidade-do-ano",
          "to_ping":"",
          "pinged":"",
          "post_modified":"2016-03-03 23:53:39",
          "post_modified_gmt":"2016-03-03 23:53:39",
          "post_content_filtered":"",
          "post_parent":0,
          "guid":"http://raphaelk.co/api/?post_type=imoveis&p=149",
          "menu_order":0,
          "post_type":"imoveis",
          "post_mime_type":"",
          "comment_count":"0",
          "filter":"raw"
       },

Do you guys have any idea how can i change that response? And include ACF to it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to simply use the ACF function `get_fields` ?

In your "busca" function, after `get_posts()`, if `$posts` isn't empty, retrieve acf fields for each posts like this :

```
if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
  return new WP_Error( 'sem resultados', 'quartos: ' . $data['quartos'] . ' transacao: '. $data['tipo'], array( 'status' => 404 ) );
} else {
    foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
        $posts[$key]->acf = get_fields($post->ID);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that'll do it !

Comment: @RaphaelKoszalka Happy to help ! Don't forget to accept the answer. ;)

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to do that the first time.
Done, answer accepted!