# Front End post into Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields with javascript

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to put out a form on the front end of wordpress, and be able to post the data into Advanced Custom Fields. However, it seems I only have access to 'title' and 'content'.
Am I able to target the custom fields from JS file specifically?

Below code line 5, I tried using "getField('chapter'): $(".chapter").val(),", but it doesn't work.

```
postNote(e) {
    var ournewPost ={
        'title': $(".new-note-title").val(),
        'content': $(".new-note-body").val(),
        getField('chapter'): $(".chapter").val(),
        'status': 'publish'
    }
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: (xhr) => {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', Data.nonce);
        },
        url: Data.root_url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/note/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: newNote,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the endpoints in Wordpress Rest API for your advanced custom fields. There is a plugin for this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/  * (see end of answer for alternative)

You then can have a look with a RESTClient (Postman or something similar) and make sure that the field is in your response: `https://www.yourwordpressurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/note/`

If you can find your field, you will also see how to access it by the name and path (you easily will find `content` and `title` you are already using. It may be inside of a `acf:` I guess, you need to have a look what the structure looks like.

Things can just be chained up:

`['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].media_details.sizes.medium_large.source_url`

for getting the url of your medium sized featured image.
It depens on your field:

`[acf] ....`

With this scheme you should be able to find the right way to access your data.

---

*If you like to add your endpoint programmatically, there is a helpful question here on SO:
[Adding ACF to CUSTOM wp api endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924138/adding-acf-to-custom-wp-api-endpoints)

Comment: Thank you. That made a lot of sense. Now let me figure out how to do it.